# Why Appharbor not create all tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, appharbor

Why Appharbor not create all tables.

I have the following Entity Framework Configuration.

```
public class RezaWebContext : DbContext
{
    public RezaWebContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RegistrantInfo> RegistrantInfos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<RegistrantInfo>().HasRequired(x => x.UserProfile).WithOptional(x => x.RegistrantInfo);
    }
}

public class RegistrantInfo
{
    public virtual int RegistrantInfoId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Sex { get; set; }
    public virtual string BirthPlace { get; set; }
    public virtual string BirthDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address { get; set; }
    public virtual string ExamNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}

//this tables used by ASP.Net Simple Membership
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual RegistrantInfo RegistrantInfo { get; set; }
}    

connString :
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server=localhost\SqlExpress; database=RezaWeb; 
user id=sa; password=123456; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

in my computer. All database tables created.
RegistrationInfo + SimpleMembership tables (UserProfile, webpages_Membership, webpages_OAuthMembership, webpages_Roles, webpages_UsersInRoles)

in appharbor : all SimpleMembership tables created but "RegistrationInfo" table not created.

Why ?

Comment: can you please remove virtual keyword for RegistrantInfo POCO properties and keep virtual for UserProfile because it is used for lazy loading.

Comment: other wise see ... http://www.lynda.com/ASPNET-tutorials/Deploying-AppHarbor/170334/191141-4.html